# How to display the data only once by using two query results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How do i avoid repeatedly printing datas on my view page..I tried this query in my phpmyadmin it display the correct result..But i am getting the  data printed multiple times..How do i avoid that..I tried 
`$this->db->distinct();`
`$this->db->group_by(vno)..`
but i didn't get the expected result..Help me to achieve this..Here is my tried code:

Controller code:

```
$this->db->where('billdate >=', $newDate);
$this->db->where('billdate <=', $newDate2);
$this->db->select('');
$this->db->from('purchaseitem');
$this->db->distinct();
//$this->db->join('purchasebill', 'purchasebill.no = purchaseitem.billno','left outer');
$this->db->join('itemmaster','itemmaster.itcode = purchaseitem.Product_Code','left outer');
$query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
$data['query'] = $query;
$this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
$this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('purchasebill');
$this->db->order_by('voucherno');
$this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
$query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
$data['query1'] = $query;

$this->load->view('Receipt_View1', $data);
```

[image: My Current output]

View Code:

```
<?php $rowcount = 1 ?>                          
<?php foreach ($query1 as $row): ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?=$rowcount;?></td>
            <td><?=$row['voucherno'];?></td>
            <td><?=$row['date'];?></td>
            <td><?=$row['PName'];?></td>
            <?php $rowcount +=1?>
            <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>
                <tr>
            <td><?=$row['itemname'];?></td>
            <td><?=$row['Qty'];?></td>
            <td><?=$row['bundle'];?></td>

            <?php endforeach ?> 
            <?php endforeach ?> 
        </tr></tr>
        <?php $total_qty=0; ?>  
    <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
            <?php $total_qty += $row['Qty'];?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php $total_bundle=0; ?>   
    <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
            <?php $total_bundle += $row['bundle'];?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

The problem lies in purchaseitem table because according to the voucher no it have to print entries on the table but it's printing all the datas that is available on from date and to date.. i tried by putting a where condition but it's results nothing from the table..any ideas for how do i specify voucher no..Here is my where code`$this->db->where('vocuerno','vno`)..i have voucher no on both purchase item and purchase bill table

Comment: If you could highlight where exactly in your code the problem lies, it might help you to get an answer faster here.

Comment: The problem is in purchaseitem table...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GROUP_BY in the second query, not in the first part.

Try adding it here, showing from row 10 in your controller code

```
....

$this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
$this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
$this->db->from('purchasebill');
$this->db->order_by('voucherno');
$this->db->group_by('voucherno'); // <- HERE
$this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
$query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
$data['query1'] = $query;
```

Comment: Tried but not get the expected output